# How do I create and initialise a simple struct without providing a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have this type:

```
struct T
{
  SomeType a;
  OtherType b;
};
```

I think there is some way to declare an object of type `T` and defining the initialised values of `a` and `b` in line, but I can't remember how this worked, or even what it's called so I can look it up. Something like `T t(a, b)` where `a` and `b` are of type `SomeType` and `OtherType` respectively.

How do I achieve this without declaring a constructor, and what is it called?

Comment: google "c++11 struct initialization" first [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write `T t = {a, b}`. That only works with <s>PODs</s> [aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178176/3484570) though (or with a propper constructors of course).

Comment: Cool. Can I create an rvalue as well? Like `T{a,b}`?

Answer (score 3):

You tagged with c++11, so do very simply this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct T
{   
    int a;
    float b;
};  


int main()
{   
    T t{1,2.2};

    std::cout << t.a << ":" << t.b << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Which is called aggregate-initialization.

Comment: As dyp said, this is aggregate initialization and works with C++03 compilers as well. It looks like you might be conflating it with C++11's list initialization.

Comment: @Praetorian In C++03, this will only work if written as `T t = {1,2.3};`

Answer (score 0):

C++11 suports unified inicializatoin list with "{}", which means you can init. classes with "{}" as a struct before
you can initialize the the struct like this

```
T t{someTypeA, otherTypeB};// someTypeA and someTypeB must be defined
```

here is a simple test code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    int a;
};

class C
{
public:
    int a;
};

struct A
{
    B b;
    C c;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    B b;
    C c;
    b.a = 1;
    c.a = 2;
    A a{b, c};
    cout << a.b.a << a.c.a << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```